# Can't start sshd service on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: ssh, openssh

when I enter commnad:

```
sshd.exe -d
```

I can ssh to this computer by another computer.

But I can't start ssh server as service:

```
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service sshd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting the computer after setup?

Depending on your version of Windows, you probably need to fix the file permissions to the hosts file using

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1
```

Also consider using the latest version instead of the one delivered with Windows.

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

Comment: Confirmed, thanks!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as the solution to your question.